# Python How do I print a list of integer so that each element of list in new line

Tags: python, list, printing

Assume I have a list: `a = [1, 2, 3]`

and I want it to look like:

```
Item: 1
Item: 2
Item: 3
```

I have `print("Item:", *a, sep = "\n")`
but it just give me

```
Item:
 1
 2
 3
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you ever written or seen python code which prints items from a list?

Comment: Do you know how to write a for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell it to print "Item: "

```
for x in a:
    print("Item: " + a)
```

Take some time to look into "for loops" online.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension or generator expression to prefix each item with the string `Item:`  and then print them. E.g.:

```py
print(*(f'Item: {i}' for i in a), sep = '\n')
```